# how to make a list of lists with a certain width

Tags: list, prolog

i want to implement a function that make a list of sublists with a certain width. For example :

```
?- list_to_llists([w,w,w,w],2,LL). %1
LL = [[w, w], [w, w]] ;
false.
?- list_to_llists([w,w,c,l,r,w,c,c,w,w,w,w],3,LL). %2
LL = [[w, w, c], [l, r, w], [c, c, w], [w, w, w]] ;
false.
?- list_to_llists([w,w,w,w],3,LL). %3
LL = [[w, w, w]] ;
false. 

sublist(I1,I2,L,Sub)    :-
   sublist2(I1,I2,L,[],Sub).

sublist2(I1,I2,L,Sub,Sub):-
    length(Sub,N),
    N\=0,
    I1>I2.
sublist2(I1,I2,L,Sub,Sub2):-
   I1<I2,
   nth0(I1,L,X),
   I3 is I1+1,
   append(Sub,[X],Z),
   sublist2(I3,I2,L,Z,Sub2).
sublist2(A,B,L,Sub,Sub2):-
   B=A,
   nth0(A,L,X),
   NewA is A+1,
   append(Sub,[X],Z),
   sublist2(NewA,B,L,Z,Sub2).


list_to_llists(L,W,LLists):-
   length(L,X),
   X=<W,
   LLists=[L].

list_to_llists2([],W,LLists,A):- LLists=A . 
list_to_llists2(L,W,LLists,A):-
   P is W-1 ,
   sublist(0,P,L,Result),
   append([Result],A,U),
   append(Result,K,L),
   list_to_llists2(K,W,LLists,U).

list_to_llists(L,W,F):-
   list_to_llists2(L,W,R,[[]]).
```

but case 2 and 3 don't work at all

secondly, i want to implement a function that takes certain facts and put them in L where L is a list but i have to use list_to_lists to make L kind of list of lists list (*it's a map*)

for example (*test cases*):

```
?- length(L,100),ensure_hints(L, [at(3, 5, c), at(5, 0, w), at(9, 6, c)],10,10).
L = [_G1699, _G1702, _G1705, _G1708, _G1711, w, _G1717, _G1720, _G1723, _G1726,
_G1729, _G1732, _G1735, _G1738, _G1741, _G1744, _G1747, _G1750, _G1753, _G1756,
_G1759, _G1762, _G1765, _G1768, _G1771, _G1774, _G1777, _G1780, _G1783, _G1786,
_G1789, _G1792, _G1795, _G1798, _G1801, _G1804, _G1807, _G1810, _G1813, _G1816,
_G1819, _G1822, _G1825, _G1828, _G1831, _G1834, _G1837, _G1840, _G1843, _G1846,
_G1849, _G1852, _G1855, c, _G1861, _G1864, _G1867, _G1870, _G1873, _G1876,
_G1879,_G1882, _G1885, _G1888, _G1891, _G1894, _G1897, _G1900, _G1903, c,
_G1909, _G1912,_G1915, _G1918, _G1921, _G1924, _G1927, _G1930, _G1933, _G1936,
_G1939, _G1942, _G1945, _G1948, _G1951, _G1954, _G1957, _G1960, _G1963, _G1966,
_G1969,_G1972, _G1975, _G1978, _G1981, _G1984, _G1987, _G1990, _G1993, _G1996];
false
?- length(L,9),ensure_hints(L, [at(1, 2, c), at(0, 1, l)],3,3).
L = [_G1589, _G1592, _G1595, l, _G1601, _G1604, _G1607, c, _G1613] ;
false.
?- length(L,9),ensure_hints(L, [at(1, 2, c), at(0, 5, l)],3,3).
false.
```

but it doesn't work for me

my code :

```
ensure_hints(L,Hints,W,H):-
   list_to_llists(L,W,C),
   Hints=[H|T],
   H=at(X,Y,O),
   nth0(X,L,Z),
   nth0(Y,Z,O),
   ensure_hints(L,T,W,H).
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
list_to_llists(List, Len, [H|T]) :-
    length(H, Len),
    append(H, Rest, List),
    !,
    list_to_llists(Rest, Len, T).
list_to_llists(_, _, []).
```

It simple removes sublists of length `Len` until there is no complete sublist left (it seems you want to ignore incomplete sublists).

You can play with it on http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/OqfzwRoe.pl

Comment: Here, the goal `list_to_llists(List, Len, [])` is true for all `List`, `Len`.